Why it gives FALSE if we compare (if (.1 == i)) where int i = .1 as initialized and similarly if we compare(if(-1 <= SIZE)) macro SIZE to -1?
Why it gives FALSE if we compare if (.1 == i) where int i = .1 as initialized and similarly  if we compare if(-1 <= SIZE)) macro SIZE to -1?
Global arr[] calculated using #define SIZE with this value inside the main function I am comparing using if condition statement with -1, my expectation is True but the condition always checks False. Similarly, I initialized integer variable I value .1 and comparing with if condition but always checked False, please explain why?
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

#define SIZE (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]))

int main()
{
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(SIZE));
    int i = .1;
    if(i == .1) 
    {
        printf("True\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False\n");
    }
    printf("==================================\n");
    if(-1 == SIZE) 
    {
        printf("True\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False");
    } 
} 


Look up "implicit conversions" in your textbook.

.1 is a double value. There is a automatic (implicit) conversion from double to int during the assignment. The double .1 becomes the integer 0. Similarly with the comparison: the integer i (value 0) is converted to double (value 0.0) and then that is compared to the double value 0.1.

int i = .1; assigns 0 to i because it's an int. But for comparison is it converted to a floating point value (double) because of the 0.1 (which is a double), and so 0.0 != 0.1.

Sidenote: %ld is not the correct conversion specifier for sizeof(SIZE). Use %zu.

BTW: the double value 0.1 is probably not what you think: it is an approximation.

You should investigate what values your variables have in a debugger or just print them out. int i = .1; printf("i=%d\n", i); will show you that it's 0.

For the comparison (-1 <= SIZE) you also asked about, the -1 is converted to an unsigned value (to match SIZE) and becomes a large positive value.

Always compile with warnings on. For instance, with GCC: -Wall -Wextra If you really want to make sure you fix these things, turn warnings into errors: -Werror

sizeof(SIZE) is the same as sizeof(sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])) which is the same as sizeof(size_t). Why do you want that? Makes no sense

@jthill Sadly, implicit conversions is one of those things that are often left out from books and beginner learning materials. There's a summary of the most common ones here: Implicit type promotion rules

There are several issues of implicit conversions here:

Initializing i:
i is an int and so when you attempt to initialize it with .1 (which is a double value) it actually gets converted to 0 (an int value).

Comparing i:
When comparing i with if (i == .1), since .1 is a double, the value of i also gets converted to a double to perform the comparison.
And so 0.0 == 0.1 is false.

Comparing to SIZE:
SIZE is an unsigned value. Therefore, if you use if (-1 <= SIZE), the value of -1 gets converted to an unsigned value and becomes a very large positive value.
And so <large positive value> <= SIZE is false.
Note: this assumes that size_t does not have a lower rank than int (which is true on most systems). On systems where it has, SIZE will be converted to int and -1 <= SIZE will be true.


A side note:
In order to print a size_t value like sizeof(SIZE) you should use %zu, not %ld.

If size_t has lower rank than int, then SIZE will be converted to int and -1 <= SIZE will be true.

@IanAbbott I never encountered such a case, but you are correct in principle. Added a note about it.

@IanAbbott  — can you give an instance (preferably concrete, but a hypothetical if you can't name a concrete) where size_t has a lower rank than int?

@JonathanLeffler I cannot think of a genuine, real world example off the top of my head, but imagine a 16-bit x86 C compiler using a small (16-bit) data model, using 16-bit size_t, but with 32-bit int (although compilers such as Turbo C used 16-bit int).

@IanAbbott — I suppose that is just about a conceivable configuration, though not very likely.

@JonathanLeffler There is not even a "recommended practice" for the minimum rank of size_t as there is for the maximum rank.

@dineshbabu happy to help.  If my answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. With enough rep you can also upvote any helpful answer (see: What should I do when someone answers my question?.
